# how to give dc offset to the square wave from 2.5 v to -2.5 to 5 to 0 volt?

Tags: dc, pwm, square, offset

[image]

[image]

[image]

a)I want to change my square wave signal from -2.5 to 2.5 volt to 5 volts to 0 volts? actually this will be given to MOSFET driver ir2110.

b) In the first picture, it is my original square wave coming from the Lm393 comparator, but see its ground level is not in zero references, it is below to zero references, that's why I added Capacitor and resistor (100nf,12K ohms), then I get a  shape in order of 2.5 v to -2.5 volt. now I need to change my volatge in 5 volts to 0-volt reference.i have not connected my output of Lm393 comparator with hex inverter or MOSFET driver till yet.

[image]

Comment: Where is the square wave coming from?

Comment: You want inversion as well yes?

Comment: this square wave is coming from Lm393 comparator

Comment: @ Andy aka yes I need an inversion also, but before inversion, I need to add dc offset

Comment: Please add info to your question about (a) your situation and (b) why you are trying to do this.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question, I want to change my square wave signal from -2.5 to 2.5 volt to 5 volts to 0 volts. and when I will provide my signal to the MOSFET driver, the driver will take two inputs , a) High input side as a +vdd to 0voltage and b) low input side through using hex inverter.

Comment: Did I understand correctly: the +/- 2.5V signal is decoupled using a capacitor? Then you could simply achieve this offset by adding a bias voltage with a voltage divider.
What do you mean by "ground level is not coupled"? A circuit diagram would be helpful, as it is difficult to describe circuits in words.

Comment: yes, see the 1 st picture of a square wave, their grounding is below from original ground level, it is dc offset, I have removed dc offset using capacitor and resistor , afterwards, I get a +/- 2.5 v dc square wave. now my problem is I need to shift the square wave from =/-2.5 volt to 5 to 0-volt reference.

Comment: You have not - your question says only what you are trying to do, not why or for what. Please add info to your question about (a) your situation and (b) why you are trying to do this.

Comment: yes, you get the point, I am posting one more circuit, maybe you will understand

Answer (score 4):

I believe this whole question is based on the misinterpretation of the [oscilloscope screenshot shown first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH1yy.jpg), before adding a capacitor & resistor to the LM393 output.

You said:

> I want to change my square wave signal [...] 5 volts to 0 volts

This is what is shown in the first image anyway!

> In the first picture, it is my original square wave coming from the Lm393 comparator, but see its ground level is not in zero references, it is below to zero references

Not true.

The waveform is in the lower half of the display, but that does **not** mean it is negative. The ground reference level for channel 1 is the small "1" shown on the left side of the display. Notice that the whole of the waveform is positive with respect to that level.

[image: oscilloscope screenshot with ground reference marked and simulated with a red line]

Above, I have taken the original oscilloscope screenshot image, and circled the ground reference for channel 1 in red. Notice how the whole waveform is positive with respect to that. I have also added a red line which is the imaginary 0 V (ground) level for that image. As you can see, the whole waveform is above that line.

So it seems that you have introduced a new problem by adding your RC circuit, and you do not need that. The original signal is what you wanted, varying between 0 and 5 V approximately, but it was just displayed in an unexpected way so you didn't recognise it.

Comment: Thankyou finally you got my point, I am trying to explain this everyone, sir, you mean to say that in 1st picture I have already generated square wave in 5 volts to 0-volt reference. sir if I provide this signal to the MOSFET driver, did MOSFET driver  will work or will it read the signal?

Comment: Sir, only give me this answer to this problem , if I give the signal to this  MOSFET driver, and the square wave signal is 5 volt with his own ground level( or you can say it is dc offset) as seen in the oscilloscope, will MOSFET driver be confused which is the original ground level.

Comment: @SamGibsonokay, in simple words I am asking you, In lm393 comparator generates a square wave, my questions are 1)-  did the output square wave has any offset? if yes, should I need to remove the offset, else No, can I give to the MOSFET driver, will it work.

Comment: @ArijeetRoy - "*you mean to say that in 1st picture I have already generated square wave in 5 volts to 0-volt*" Yes. "*if I provide this signal to the MOSFET driver [...] will it read the signal?*" Yes. With the IR2113 powered from 5 V, the logic level thresholds (shown in the datasheet) mean that 0 V and 5 V will be recognised as logic low and high. "*did MOSFET driver will work*" I can't answer that. First, that would need a full review of the driver circuit, but that is not what you asked in the question. Second, layout is important and yours isn't built, so I can't predict the future.

Comment: Okay.only I want to ask you did output of comparator is showing offset or not ? Just give me answer of this question.

Comment: @ArijeetRoy - "*only I want to ask you did output of comparator is showing offset or not ?*" Offset to what? I don't see anything that I would call an offset. Please explain your thinking, which means that you still have a doubt about this. Perhaps you are seeing something that I am not seeing.

Comment: @SamGibsonokay, see the above picture , what I am want to ask, theoretical my PWM should lie in 5 volts to 0 volts in  XY plane, but in my oscilloscope , the practical results are not matching with theoretical results. in my oscilloscope, if press auto set, the square wave is coming below x plane, I totally understand it is a positive PWM wrt to the ground. but in my oscilloscope, the real ground is always at (0,0) coordinates.maybe you understand my point?

Comment: "*theoretical my PWM should lie in 5 volts to 0 volts in XY plane*" No, that is an abstraction, which you can change with scope settings. "*in my oscilloscope , the practical results are not matching with theoretical results*" No, you have the wrong expectation of the theoretical result. "*in my oscilloscope, the real ground is always at (0,0) coordinates*" No, that is not true. The ground reference position can always be moved. "*if press auto set [...]*" Auto-set is not guaranteed to produce the display you want. Use the scope controls to move the ground reference, if you want that.

Comment: So by your comment, I can be confirmed that my output is right, zero dc offset. Am I right? what does the mean of " you have the wrong expectation of the theoretical result"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110067/discussion-between-arijeet-roy-and-samgibson).

Comment: I'm continuing in chat, using [that link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110067/discussion-between-arijeet-roy-and-samgibson).